# Not updating two tables using inner join with PDO?

Tags: php, pdo

I want to update two tables using PDO.

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

I want to update the username and password at the same time in two tables. Both have a `user_id` field.

```
public function update($user_id, $username, $password, $province) {
    try {
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE login INNER JOIN sample ON sample.username = sample.username SET login.username = :username, sample.username=:username WHERE user_id=:user_id");
        //$stmt=$this->db->prepare("UPDATE login SET username=:username,password=:password,province=:province WHERE user_id=:user_id");
        $stmt->bindparam(":username", $username);
        $stmt->bindparam(":password", $password);
        $stmt->bindparam(":province", $province);
        $stmt->bindparam(":user_id", $user_id);
        $stmt->execute();

        return true;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your prepared query as following

```sql
UPDATE login INNER JOIN sample ON (login.user_id = sample.user_id)
SET login.username = :username, sample.username = :username
WHERE login.user_id = :user_id AND sample.user_id = :user_id
```

Here is [a visual explanation of SQL Joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/).

Comment: it work! thank you very much..can you explain me why my code is not working?

Comment: You have to use table names in `WHERE` and in `INNER JOIN ... ON` you need to compare two tables so you can't do it like `sample.username = sample.username`